# JSON for OpenWeatherMap API

Tags: jquery, json, weather-api, openweathermap

I am writing a simple one page weather app using the [Openweathermap](http://openweathermap.org) API, but I am encountering an issue looping through the nested JSON objects returned.

Here is a sample of the JSON:

```
"cod":"200",
"message":0.1986,
"city":{
    "id":"4781530",
    "name":"Reston",
    "coord":{
        "lon":-77.3545,
        "lat":38.9597
    },
    "country":"United States of America",
    "population":0
},
"cnt":2,
"list":[
    {
        "dt":1416499200,
        "temp":{
            "day":45.3,
            "min":33.48,
            "max":52,
            "night":34.47,
            "eve":50.59,
            "morn":33.48
        },
        "pressure":1015.56,
        "humidity":58,
        "weather":[
            {
                "id":801,
                "main":"Clouds",
                "description":"few clouds",
                "icon":"02d"
            }
        ],
        "speed":9.07,
        "deg":212,
        "clouds":24
    },
    {
        "dt":1416585600,
        "temp":{
            "day":33.04,
            "min":20.55,
            "max":38.86,
            "night":22.87,
            "eve":38.03,
            "morn":24.42
        },
        "pressure":1027.28,
        "humidity":50,
        "weather":[
            {
                "id":800,
                "main":"Clear",
                "description":"sky is clear",
                "icon":"01d"
            }
        ],
        "speed":7.99,
        "deg":301,
        "clouds":0
    }
]
```

}

I am able to successfully loop through the first set of values in obj.list but I get an undefined error when it reaches the     `$.each(obj.list[i].weather[i], function(key,value)` loop.

How would I loop through the nested weather and temp objects, and why does my current code given me an undefined error? I have included the code and Firebug console log. Any help with be greatly appreciated.

jQuery loop function

```
$.each(obj.list, function(i) {
    $.each(obj.list[i], function(key,value) {

        if(typeof value == "object"){
            console.log(key + " is an Object!!");

            if(key=="weather"){
                            console.log("What is i? " + i );
                            console.log(obj.list[i].weather[i]);

                            $.each(obj.list[i].weather[i], function(key,value) {
                                    console.log("weather object " + key + ": " + value );
                            });
            }

        }
        else{
            console.log("outer object " + key + ": " + value );
        }
    });
});
```

Firebug console log:

```
outer object dt: 1416499200
scripts.js (line 72)
temp is an Object!!
scripts.js (line 49)
outer object pressure: 1015.56
scripts.js (line 72)
outer object humidity: 58
scripts.js (line 72)
weather is an Object!!
scripts.js (line 49)
What is i? 0
scripts.js (line 59)
Object { id=801, main="Clouds", description="few clouds", more...}
scripts.js (line 60)
weather object id: 801
scripts.js (line 66)
weather object main: Clouds
scripts.js (line 66)
weather object description: few clouds
scripts.js (line 66)
weather object icon: 02d
scripts.js (line 66)
outer object speed: 9.07
scripts.js (line 72)
outer object deg: 212
scripts.js (line 72)
outer object clouds: 24
scripts.js (line 72)
***********
scripts.js (line 103)
outer object dt: 1416585600
scripts.js (line 72)
temp is an Object!!
scripts.js (line 49)
outer object pressure: 1027.28
scripts.js (line 72)
outer object humidity: 50
scripts.js (line 72)
weather is an Object!!
scripts.js (line 49)
What is i? 1
scripts.js (line 59)
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for only the `i`th element from each `obj.list[i].weather` list. You should loop over `obj.list[i].weather`, instead of asking for a single element from it. So, for `obj.list[0]`, you ask only for `obj.list[0].weather[0]`. For `obj.list[1]`, you ask only for `obj.list[1].weather[1]`, which doesn't exist (that `weather` list only has a single object, at index `0`).

Your `$.each(obj.list[i].weather[i], ...)` loops over `obj.list[i].weather[i]`, but you don't loop over `obj.list[i].weather`. You want something with two different looping variables, like `obj.list[i].weather[j]`, not `obj.list[i].weather[i]`.

```
    if(typeof value == "object"){
        console.log(key + " is an Object!!");

        if(key=="weather"){
                console.log("What is i? " + i );

                $.each(obj.list[i].weather, function(j) {
                    console.log(obj.list[i].weather[j]);
                    $.each(obj.list[i].weather[j], function(key,value) {
                        console.log("weather object " + key + ": " + value );
                    });
                });
        }

    }
```

Here, we add a loop over `obj.list[i].weather` with the inner loping variable `j` so that we get all of the items in each `weather` list, instead of only one..